# Why isn't this image being displayed with TimThumb?

Tags: image, image-processing, php

I am using TimThumb at http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/.

I have adjusted the memory_limit to "5000MB" in my php.ini file and in the TimThumb code I adjusted the code to the following:

```
    define ('MEMORY_LIMIT', '30M');             // set PHP memory limit
define ('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 7000000000);           // file size limit to prevent possible DOS attacks (roughly 1.5 megabytes)
```

The picture itself is only 2.23 MB, the last time I checked that wasn't that big lol.

Comment: Ha you have a server called Hermes too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use ini_set(), not a define() to change php settings:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','64M');
```

edit: noticed the memory it reports is 30M, so maybe the thumbnail script uses the defined value. Either way, just increase your memory limit until it works.

Comment: Is there a way to set the memory limit to "unlimited"?

Comment: `ini_set(memory_limit, -1)` , but that's generally a **really** bad idea.